# Drawbacks of sending sql commands (and receiving selected data) over HTTP(s)

Tags: http, webapi

In context of Web APIs, what may be the drawbacks and risks in sending sql commands (and receiving selected data) over HTTP(s)? Command types may include DML and DDL.
I have over-viewed other methods like GraphQL and OData and am least concerned with returned data shape/format.

Comment: Do you plan to issue SQL statements from a web page that the users will be using?

Comment: a web page or any http client.

Comment: Well, such strategy is dangerous as it would allow any user (with minimal technical knowledge) to destroy or corrupt your database by issuing rogue SQL statements.

Comment: Consider using a restful API